# jmeter : while controller and csv

Tags: jmeter

I am unable to execute all the GET requests to the list of URL given in the CSV file.

The sequence of execution is as follows:

```
 Thread Group
         HTTP Authorization Manager
          While Controller
                 CSV Reader
                 HTTP Sampler
       Summary Results
```

The questions is what to specify in while controller so that all the list of url's specified in while controller are invoked?

I tried both with javascript and beanshell evaluation:

```
    ${__BeanShell(!"${URL}".equals("end"))}
```

and also with `${URL}` - yet not all records get processed - any idea how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was related to firewall authentication. There is some firewall authentication that is done prior to accessing pages - but that is a one time activity. However, for Jmeter, this authentication has to be part of the script otherwise the pages are not accessible after a period of time.

So the work around is to first have the firewall authentication done as part of Jmeter script and then proceed with the page access.

Answer (score 1):

While evaluates a TRUE/FALSE statement.  Once the statement reads FALSE, it will stop.

So, to answer your question, you  need to specify something that will return TRUE while you want the children to run, and FALSE when you want it to stop.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller